# In TCL, How do I make a variable use the value of another variable

Tags: tcl

I need to use the value of a variable inside another variable.

This is what I tried..

```
set cmd_ts "foo bar"
set confCmds {
    command1
    command2
    $cmd_ts
}
puts "confCmds = $confCmds"
```

But instead of getting

```
confCmds = 
    command1
    command2
    foo bar
```

I am getting:

```
confCmds =
    command1
    command2
    $cmd_ts
```

P.S. I tried the following to no avail

1. $cmd_ts
2. "$cmd_ts"
3. {$cmd_ts}
4. \$cmd_ts

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(almost) nothing will work as long as you use curly braces. The best suggestion is to use the list command:

```
set confCmds [list command1 command2 $cmd_ts]
```

I say (almost) because you can use subst to do variable substitution on confCmds, but that's not really what you want and that is fraught with peril. What you want is a list of words, one or more of which may be defined by a variable. That is precisely what the above solution gives you.

If you want, you can spread the commands on more than one line by using the backslash:

```
set confCmds [list \
    command1 \
    command2 \
    $cmd_ts \
]
```

This solution assumes that what you want is a tcl list. This may or may not be what you want, it all depends on how you treat this data downstream.

In a comment you wrote that what  you really want is a string of newline-separated items, in which case you can just use double quotes, for example:

```
set confCmds "
    command1
    command2
    $cmd_ts
"
```

That will give you a string with multiple lines separated by newlines. Be careful of trying to treat this as a list of commands (ie: don't do 'foreach foo $confCmds') because it can fail depending on what is in $cmd_ts.

Comment: Actually I want command1, command2 and $cmd_ts to be separated by a new line, but using list or concat I get them together as a space delimited string. Any idea how to achieve that as I am facing a rough time tackling \n :P

Comment: You can use double quotes instead of curly braces in your original example. As long as you not later treating this data as a Tcl list you'll be fine. Another option is to convert the tcl list you just created into a string of newline separated items with [join $confCmds \n]

Answer (score 4):

Bryan's answer is good, apart from a typo I can't fix with my rep. (the list in the first command should be ended with a square bracket).

If you want to do anything useful with the commands, you probably want them as a list, but if you just want them separated by a new line do this at the end:

```
set confCmds [join $confCmds "\n"]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you must have the list defined as you have it, you can also use the subst command, which will perform the substitution that the curly braces are preventing:

```
subst $confCmds
```